# How to retrieve a value from HashMap with optional argument

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am learning Java 8 streams and I am trying to refactor a method.

Say I have a School class and a `school map` that stores all school objects by Id. Each school object contains a `student map` that stores a bunch of students.

In this scenario, the student Ids are unique across the schools.

I have a function that retrieves a student by the id across all schools.

```
public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap, String studentId) {
    return schoolMap.values().stream()
                             .map(School::getStudentIdToStudentMap)
                             .filter(map -> map.containsKey(studentId))
                             .map(map -> map.get(studentId))
                             .findAny().get();
}
```

Now, I want to change the function to use `schoolId` as a filter if available.

```
public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap, 
                          String schoolId /* can be null */, 
                          String studentId) 
{
    // TODO: Something that I have tried
    return schoolMap.get(schoolId)
                    .getStudentIdToStudentMap()
                    .get(studentId);
}
```

Is there a good way I can combine these two functions? If `schoolId` is null, get the student from all schools. Else just lookup in the particular school and retrieve the student?

Comment: Why not just used two separate methods, with two descriptive names that clearly explain the different behaviours: `getStudentFromAnySchool` and `getStudentFromSchool`? I'm not seeing the benefit of an all-in-one method.

Comment: Use a `Predicate<SchoolId>`? Then use `id -> true` for one and `id -> id.equals(requiredId)` for the other? Fundamentally though - an approach that loops over `Map` is usally wrong.

Comment: Don't call `get()` at the end unconditionally.  Call one of the safe methods (`orElse()`, `orElseThrow()`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet this is what are you looking for:

```
public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap, String schoolId, String studentId)
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(schoolId)             // schoolId might be null
          .map(id -> Stream.of(schoolMap.get(id)))   // get Stream<School> by  else
          .orElse(schoolMap.values().stream())       // ... get Stream of all Schools
          .flatMap(i -> i.getStudentIdToStudentMap() // students from 1/all schools ...
                         .entrySet().stream())       // flat map to Stream<Entry<..,..>>
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(                 // collect all entries bu key/value
              Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))       // ... Map<String,Student> 
          .getOrDefault(studentId, null);            // get Student by id or else null
}
```

You have to search in either the only known school or in all the schools. The idea is based on the common characteristics of the searching process. The finding in any school remains the same regardless you iterate one known school or all the ones.

Alternatively get `List<Student>` from `Optional`,

```
public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap, String schoolId, String studentId)
{
    return Optional.ofNullable(schoolId)                          // schoolId might be null
           .map(i -> Collections.singletonList(schoolMap.get(i))) // add School into List
           .orElse(new ArrayList<>(schoolMap.values()))           // ... else all schools
           .stream()
           .map(i -> i.getStudentIdToStudentMap()       // get Map of students from 1/all
                      .get(studentId))                  // ... find by studentId
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)                    // get rid of nulls
           .findFirst().orElse(null);                   // get Student by id or else null
}
```

Comment: This is a abuse of `Optional` and makes it more unclear.

Comment: @Lino: Thanks for the comment. This is a correct way of treating Optional. I only answered the question “Is there a good way to combine these two functions?”. It’s a bit overkill, but definetly not an abuse. We are on the same page the method should be broken to smaller pieces, personally I’d use your snippet in my code rather. However, the question is about combining them together. Not all the questions are meant to be in the production code. I find appropriate to learn and discover the possibilities and limitations of Stream API and Optional in all the ways.

Comment: I disagree. `Optional`s were intended to be *returned*. To let the caller of a method handle the case itself of an absent value, rather than encountering a NPE. So using it for conditional situations, is IMO an abuse. Though I still appreciate your answer, I just wanted to point this out :)

Answer (score 2):

This would be the clearest way IMO:

```
public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap,
                          String schoolId /* can be null */,
                          String studentId){
    if(schoolId == null){
        return getStudent(schoolMap, studentId); // delegate to overload
    } else{
        return schoolMap.get(schoolId)
            .getStudentIdToStudentMap()
            .get(studentId);
    }
}
```

It is not always needed to do everything with streams. So split the two apart. Either search through all maps with streams, or just select the student from the schoold where you have the id from.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   public Student getStudent(Map<String, School> schoolMap, 
                              String schoolId /* can be null */, 
                              String studentId) {

        return schoolMap.entries()
                .stream().filter(
               //Either there is no id so all schools match or you match on the one 
               //you want
             entry -> schoolId == null || entry.getKey().equals(schoolId))
            .map(map -> map.getValue().get(studentId))
                .findAny()
                .get()
    }
```

Comment: Rather defeates the purpose of a `Map`. Before the OPs code did a `Map` lookup `O(1)` then another `Map` lookup `O(1)`. Now it **always** searches the entire `schoolMap`, for `O(s)` (where `s` is the number of schools) even when an `O(1)` lookup would suffice. This is a bad idea.